# Why isnt this div containing the ul

Tags: html, css

```
     <div class="pull_down">
       <ul class="zvuc">
         <li class="prod">
           <div class="conutine">
             <div class="prod_name"><a href="">Asus 15.6-Inch Versati...</a></div>
             <img src="../images/test/lotr.jpg">
             <div class="timer"></div>
           </div>
         </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.pull_down
{
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
}

li.prod
{
    background: url("../images/test/bg-horizontal.png") no-repeat;
    height: 286px;
    width: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0;
    display: list-item;
    width: 170px;
    min-height: 286px;
    float: left;

}
ul
{
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

When i mouse over the division with firebug, it doesn't contain anything. Why is this?

Comment: You'll have to be a little more specific, I don't quite understand what the problem is.  By the way, here's a jsfiddle for it, http://jsfiddle.net/JTwzp/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are floating your LI's so you most likely need a "clearfix" on the parent DIV.

A "clearfix" will force an element to self-clear it's children.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/Dxkpx/

You can just add the `.group` classes to your CSS file and add `class="group"` to any parent that you need to clearfix.

This is a semantic and scale-able solution. You should avoid adding empty DIVs to your markup or extra CSS to parents (such as floats). That can produce undesirable results and become confusing in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to add **`<div style="clear:both"></div>`** after the **`</ul>`** to close the float
or to add **`float: left;`** to the class .div.pull_down

Comment: Thanks, fixed it with float :). Can you explain a bit further why is float neccesary here instead of float:none?

Comment: Floating the parent DIV is going to change the width of the DIV from the default 100% to the width of the containing content. This is not an ideal solution.

Comment: as long as the element inside the div is on float the div "doesn't see it" unless the div is also floated or the is some element inside the div that is not floated